# What are the activities that are proven in Ahadith to have taken place in mosque other than worshipping?

Tags: reference-request, masjid

I would like to know what are the activities that were proven in Ahadith to have taken place in mosques other than obviously praying, worshipping and Friday sermons.

Note that I am not asking to list, categorically, what are the activities that are allowed or what are not as that is opinion based. But, if there is a text  saying that the Prophet or Sahabah disapproved any of the activity then that information may be included alongside that particular activity.

Comment: I don't get your question are you looking for activities other than prayer that took place in the mosque and were reported in ahadith or of disapproved activities or both?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Both. What I actually mean by the last sentence is sometimes a thing, like for example, the case of a man declaring about something he lost in the Masjid. This comes under activities too. But, the Prophet disapproved of it. So, if there is an activity but there is also disapproval (or approval - this is implicit, if there's no disapproval) of the same by the Prophet or Sahabah, then that information should also be mentioned alongside that activity if not already included.